# Number of Instructions Flushed?

Tags: assembly, cpu, mips

How many instructions are flushed when a jump instruction is executed?

Comment: Depends on the cpu, the depth of the pipeline, etc... e.g. your question cannot be answered.

Comment: add more information so we can help you

Comment: A general explanation of how it works would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of instructions is based on many, many variables, but for MIPS essentially comes down to the size of the pipeline in stages. For a 5-stage pipeline there are **up to** 5 instructions in some stage of execution at any given point in time. There could be less, as the pipeline could be not full after a context switch or a fault.

For out-of-order execution, you will get a variable number of instructions depending on the instruction stream coming in, among other things.

For a processor that has a separate FPU outside (or any other co-processor, for that matter) may have more instructions still.

Comment: thanks a lot, this makes a lot of sense!